# Bootstrap Scripts vs Custom AMI for making EC2 easy to rebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I have an EBS backed EC2 web server. I am trying to get to the point where I can automate launching an *identical* server (identical in terms of software and config).

From my understanding there are two ways to achieve this:

1. Install all required software, make config changes and then create a custom AMI from the EBS volume. Use this AMI to launch any future instances.
2. Use the original AMI and use a Bootstrap Script install all the required software and make necessary config changes.

To me, creating a custom AMI and not having to write a script seems a lot easier initially. But Im aware that any modifications to the server will mean creating a new AMI. I can also see how a bootstrap script is much more transparent and allows one to easily inspect what is going to be installed/configured.

I wondered if anyone could point out anymore advantages/disadvantages between the two approaches. Is there one which is considered best practice?

Comment: Is this programming one? I recommend you to ask this in the aws forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create custom AMI:

- It'll be faster to provision new servers.
- It'll be easy to maintain the unification of the environment.
- It'll be difficult to update the AMI in-case of any modifications.

If you use bootstrapping script:

- It'll be easier to modify in case of any changes.
- It'll be hard to maintain the unification of the environment (e.g. can face versioning issues).
- Slow to provision new servers.

BTW, how about using AMI for things that are less likely to change and then using bootstrap scripts e.g. user data to do things that'll change over time.